# For Monitoring JVMs with JMX, is it better to use build your own tool or use something like JConsole

Tags: jmx, jconsole

I am currently tasked with developing a tool to use JMX to monitor JVMs for things like, but not limited too, memory usage, heap size, thread count.  The desired tool is one that can display many graphs for each jvm next to each other (example below).

So the question is it best to build your own? Use another tool that is out there? (if so which one(s)) Or is there a tool that has a license, which I can build off of?

Example: (Each JVM has many graphs that are viewable at once so you can see if a specific application / server / jvm is acting up fairly easily.

1. JVM1: PermGen graph,  Heap Size graph,  Threads graph
2. JVM2: PermGen graph,  Heap Size graph,  Threads graph
3. JVM3: PermGen graph,  Heap Size graph,  Threads graph

***Edit: "You forgot the third option... Buy one."
Any in particular that could match those requirements? or be extensible enough to handle them?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what both jConsole and VisualVM do - both are distributed with JDK-6.

Comment: i agree.  JVisualVm will monitor multiple consoles and you could use a service wrapper like YAJSW if your worried about keeping it running and continually logging.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) delivers Java monitoring and management.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-wp-2008279.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Web Services Connector for Java Management Extensions (JMX) Agents](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=262), which seem to be planned for Java 7, offer an easy way to implement such a tool in any language. It is a web service / http based JMX agent standard, and can also be used to request diagnostic information from the JVM.

Actually I am trying this with Delphi and it works quite good already (using the reference implementation  [ws-jmx-connector](https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/)). It is already a very JConsole-like application, but without graphs.

I will try to implement a graphical monitor view in a free demo application for my library, which is not yet available for public download.

Comment: It seems that JSR-262 won't become a standard anytime soon. The JSR's status is set to inactive and there has been no update to the draft since May 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jmxtrans at all? (https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans).  Is very extensible and may have what you are looking for.

Comment: jmstrans + graphite is pretty powerful, yet very complicated to setup.